# Являются ли цифры в числе элементами последовательности цифр натуральных чисел?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть бесконечная последовательность натуральных чисел, записанная в виде отдельных элементов/цифр:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3
```

Это последовательность натуральных чисел, развёрнутая в отдельные цифры.

Как определить, не является ли число, например 22324, частью последовательности? На самом деле является (2 2 2 3 2 4).
Только перебором получается.

А еще есть варианты?

Comment: ну один раз придется пробежаться по последовательности все равно. можете завести массив в котором посчитать количество вхождения каждой цифры в последовательности и потом убедится что цифр хватает на число. либо бежать по последовательности и удалять из числа найденную цифру, как осталось 0 значит все нашли

Comment: Не очень понятно, как может быть бесконечной последовательность, если она задана перечислением её элементов.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Какой поиск вы хотите реализовать: поиск подстроки (подряд элементы идут), поиск подпоследовательности (элементы могут идти не подряд, но в том же порядке должны быть как и во входном числе), поиск всех чисел с повторениями без учёта порядка, поиск набора уникальных цифр из заданного числа в заданной последовательности цифр (как заголовок намекает). Как точно последовательность вам дана? Как проверять будете код? Фраза "натуральное число" у вас в значении "цифры десятичной системы" употребляется, что не одно и то же.

Comment: Спасибо. Речь идет о поиске подпоследовательности приведенного выше вида. Основная последоватьльность состоит из цифр десятичной системы, однако цифры эти - это разделенные на части  числа, т.е. 2223 (Две тысячи двести двадцать три) это цифры 2 2 2 3, и эта подпоследовательность расположена там, где 22 и 23, а также где число 2223 и в многих местах далее. мне нужно первое вхождение.

Comment: @JonnyShopkins ясно: вы ищете подстроку (подряд идущие заданные одиночные цифры типа 2 2 2 3). Я сперва не узнал последовательность натуральных чисел, развёрнутую в отдельные цифры, типа: `g = (digit for number in itertools.count(1) for digit in map(int, str(number)))` (не самый эффективный способ сгенерировать эту последовательность). А результат это наименьший индекс `i`  в этой последовательности такой что: `list(itertools.islice(g, i, i+len(digits))) == digits`, где `digits = [2,2,2,3]` (ввод). Отредактируйте ваш вопрос для ясности.

Comment: @Александр это последовательность натуральных чисел (их бесконечное число), развёрнутая в отдельные цифры (см. пример кода для `g` выше).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любое положительное целое число является частью последовательности натуральных чисел, поэтому цифры этого числа будут входить в последовательность цифр натуральных чисел.

Если не требуется минимальный индекс вхождения в последовательности найти, то возможно даже замкнутую формулу придумать, чтобы найти индекс, где  заданное число находится (см. ниже).

Можно периодичность во входном числе эксплуатировать, чтобы найти примерное место, где поиск проводить если нужен именно  *наименьший* индекс найти.

К примеру, если цифры числа образуют последовательность:

```
[d, d+1, d+2, d+3]
```

То сразу ясно что наименьший индекс в самом начале последовательности (натуральные числа с одной цифрой):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Если ввод (период=1):

```
[d, x, d+1, x]
```

то индекс, среди цифр, образованных подряд идущими двухзначными натуральными числами.

Если ввод выглядит как (период=2):

```
[x,y,d,x,y,d+1]
```

то число может быть образовано трёхзначными числами, итд.

Пример из вопроса: `22324` выглядит как второй случай (период=1): `[d,x,d+1,x,d+2]`—это говорит что число находится в районе двухзначных чисел, которые начинаются на `x=2` и пересекается с цифрами подпоследовательности `n`, `n+1`, `n+2`, где `n=22`. Поэтому ответ для `22324`—это индекс первой цифры `n` в последовательности из вопроса плюс индекс, где входное число в `n` начинается.

Если `k`, количество цифр в `n`, то индекс `n` равен: `sum((j+1)*9*10**j for j in range(k)) + (n-10**(k-1))*k` (количество цифр, необходимых для всех чисел с меньшим количеством цифр (`<k`) плюс количество цифр с тем же количеством (k), которые идут перед `n`). Сумму можно [в виде формулы переписать без цикла](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28j%2B1%29*9*10%5Ej%2Cj%3D0..k-1).

Для `n=22`: `9+(22-10)*2`

Поэтому ответ `33+1` для 22324. Можно его проверить:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> g = (digit for number in itertools.count(1) for digit in map(int, str(number)))
>>> digits = 2, 2, 3, 2, 4
>>> i=9+(22-10)*2 + 1; list(itertools.islice(g, i, i+len(digits)))
[2, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

`+1` это смещение внутри `n`, где `digits` начинаются в этом случае.

Если количество цифр на входе небольшое, то *период* можно найти простым перебором внутри числа (база log n, что гораздо лучше перебора по самой последовательности `n log n`). Когда число содержит переход между разрядами, к примеру: `8192021`, что соответствует последовательности `18 19 20 21`—можно как специальный случай обрабатывать (по наличию 9 и/или 0).

Можно обойтись без специальных случаев и попробовать все возможные начальные позиции в `n` и все возможные размеры `n`. Этот подход также не требует перебора последовательности.

Чтобы найти *минимальный* индекс в последовательности цифр натуральных чисел где встречается заданное число:

```
def find_min_index(number):
    # O(k**4) if get_digits() is O(k**2) (due to str(number))
    digits = get_digits(number)
    k = len(digits) # number of digits
    # find minimal n and start,end such that digits =
    #   = get_digits(n)[start:] + get_digits(n+1) + ... + get_digits(n+m)[:end]
    # brute force approach
    for ndigits_in_n in range(1, k):  # m ~ k / ndigits_in_n
        for start in range(ndigits_in_n):
            i = ndigits_in_n - start  # where (n+1) starts in *digits*
            # is10pow = (10**ndigits_in_n == (n+1))
            is10pow = same_start(digits[i:i + ndigits_in_n + 1], [1] + [0] * ndigits_in_n)
            # get_digits(n+1) == digits[i:i+ndigits_in_n+is10pow]
            end = i + ndigits_in_n + is10pow
            if end <= k: # enough space for all digits of (n+1) in *digits*
                n = digits2number(digits[i:end]) - 1
            elif start == 0: # all digits of n are in *digits*
                n = digits2number(digits[:ndigits_in_n])
            else:
                continue #NOTE: assume at least one of n or n+1 is in *digits* as a whole
            if matched_n(digits, n, start):
                return get_index(n) + start
    return get_index(number)  # m == 0
```

Пример:

```
>>> find_min_index(22324)
34 # верно
```

где `get_digits(number)` возвращает цифры для переданного числа:

```
def get_digits(number):
    """
    >>> get_digits(22324)
    [2, 2, 3, 2, 4]
    """
    return list(map(int, str(number)))  # NOTE: O(k**2) in CPython
```

а `digits2number(digits)` выполняет обратную операцию: возвращает число, соответствующее переданным цифрам:

```
import functools

def digits2number(digits):
    """
    >>> digits2number([1,2,3])
    123
    """
    return functools.reduce(lambda number, digit: 10 * number + digit, digits)
```

`same_start(L1, L2)` определяет одинаково ли последовательности начинаются—все соответствующие элементы должны быть равны, но длина может отличаться:

```
def same_start(L1, L2):
    """Whether L1[:k] == L2[:k] where k = min(len(L1), len(L2))"""
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(L1, L2))
```

`matched_n(digits, n, start)` проверяет находятся ли переданные цифры `digits` в указанном месте в последовательности цифр натуральных чисел—место задаётся с помощью натурального числа `n` и позиции в нём `start`:

```
import itertools

def matched_n(digits, n, start):
    """Check whether *digits* =
       = get_digits(n)[start:] + get_digits(n+1) + ... + get_digits(n+m)[:end]

    """
    g = (digit for number in itertools.count(n + 1) for digit in get_digits(number))
    return same_start(digits, itertools.chain(get_digits(n)[start:], g))
```

`get_index(number)` возвращает позицию цифр натурального числа `number` в рассматриваемой последовательности:

```
def get_index(number):
    """sum((j + 1) * 9 * 10**j for j in range(k - 1)) + (n - 10**(k - 1)) * k

    >>> get_index(22)
    33
    """
    k = ndigits10(number) - 1
    return ((9 * k - 1) * 10**k + 1) // 9 + (number - 10**k) * (k + 1)
```

где `ndigits10(number)` возвращает сколько цифр в десятичной системе необходимо для представления переданного натурального числа `number`:

```
import math

def ndigits10(number):
    """The number of decimal digits in the natural *number*.

    >>> ndigits10(1)
    1
    >>> ndigits10(99)
    2
    >>> ndigits10(100)
    3
    >>> ndigits10(101)
    3
    """
    assert number > 0
    # 10**(k-1) <= number < 10**k
    return math.floor(math.log10(number)) + 1
```

---

> **Q:** Что такое is10pow? Для чего это?

В Питоне, `True == 1 and 0 == False`.

`is10pow` говорит является ли `(n+1)` степенью десятки. Назначение переменной понять, равно ли количество цифр в `n` и `n+1`. Количество цифр в `(n+1)` всегда равно `ndigits_in_n + is10pow`, то есть либо оно равно числу цифр в `n` либо на единицу больше.

Пример:

- `n=98`, тогда `ndigits10(n) == ndigits10(n+1) == 2`
- `n=99`, тогда `ndigits10(n) == (ndigits10(n+1) - 1) == 2`

> Первый цикл это перебор по цифрам в числе,
>   второй это перебор по каждому числу на предмет соответствия последовательности,
>   i это разница для перебора

Внешний цикл перебирает все возможные размеры `n` числа: `ndigits_in_n`—это количество цифр в `n`.

Вложенный цикл перебирает все возможные стартовые позиции в цифрах `n`. В вашем примере, `22324` начинается со *второй* цифры (`start=1`).

`i`—это индекс, где `(n+1)` цифры начинаются в заданных `digits`.

Назначение кода перебрать все кандидаты для `n`, которые возможны при заданных `ndigits_in_n`, `start`, `digits`, чтобы найти то `n` для которого выполняется:

```
get_digits(n)[start:] == digits[:i]
get_digits(n+1) == digits[i:i+ndigits_in_n+is10pow]
digits == get_digits(n)[start:] + get_digits(n+1) + ... + get_digits(n+m)[:end]
```

Если не найдено, то возвращается индекс для самого `number` (все цифры к одному натуральному числу относятся и это число равно `number`).

Comment: ну чисто с формальной стороны - пусть это одно число из середины этого ряда) минимальность не требуется... Решение в 1 строку.

Comment: @pavel если минимальность не требуется, то можно `get_index(n)` использовать (замкнутая формула). Если уж совсем формальным быть, то ответ на вопрос "является ли" одно слово: *«да»* (для любого целого положительного числа во вводе).

Comment: @pavel: [автор в комментарии упомянул: *"мне нужно первое вхождение."*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582938/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb#comment777002_582938) (то есть минимальный индекс нужен).

Comment: @jfs Спасибо большое за вашу работу. Я проверяю и изучаю ваш ответ. Вопрос: я правильно понимаю, что в функции def matched_n(digits, n, start) последовательность генерится с числа в котором находится первая цифра и дальше до того числа, где находится последняя цифра из введенных? Т.е. для 22324 генератор генерит последовательность 22 23 24 и на этом заканчивает?

Comment: @JonnyShopkins: верно: если `digits=[2,2,3,2,4]; n=22; start=1`, то метод сравнивает цифры из `digits` списка с цифрами, получающимися из 22,23,24,... последовательности, начиная со `start` цифры в `22` и пока `digits` не закончится или отличие не найдено—что раньше (предполагая Питон 3 семантику).

Comment: for ndigits_in_n in range(1, k):  # m ~ k / ndigits_in_n
        for start in range(ndigits_in_n):
            i = ndigits_in_n - start  # where (n+1) starts in *digits*
            
            is10pow = same_start(digits[i:i + ndigits_in_n + 1], [1] + [0] * ndigits_in_n </br>Первый цикл это перебор по цифрам в числе, второй это перебор по каждому числу на предмет соответствия последовательности, i это разница для перебора. Что такое is10pow? Для чего это?

Comment: @jfs я немного запутался в вашем коде. В предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: @JonnyShopkins ответил ли я на ваш вопрос?

Comment: @jfs Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему с числом 10 не работает?

Comment: @JonnyShopkins что значит не работает. Что вы ожидали получить? что вместо этого происходит? И какой именно код используется?

Comment: @jfc ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 88 print find_min_index(10)

<ipython-input-74-d920366ccee0> in find_min_index(number)
   
---> 21             if matched_n(digits, n, start):
  
<ipython-input-74-d920366ccee0> in matched_n(digits, n, start)
   
---> 54     return same_start(digits, itertools.chain(get_digits(n)[start:], g))
   
<ipython-input-74-d920366ccee0> in get_digits(number)
   
---> 30     return list(map(int, str(number)))  # NOTE: O(k**2) in CPython
 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: @jfc я использовал ваш код, представленный выше.
Т.е. find_min_index(10) не выдает значение 10, как должен. Я не могу справиться с ошибкой :(
100 и 1000 выдают то же

Comment: @JonnyShopkins: я могу воспроизвести ошибку. Это выглядит как баг.  Я не помню код в достаточной мере, чтобы исправить не разбираясь заново. Если код ломается только на числах вида `10**k`, то можно как специальный случай обработать, но могут быть и более глубокие проблемы с кодом.

Comment: @jfc, вроде бы да, только на числах вида 10**k. Может быть поможете обработать специальный случай?

Comment: @JonnyShopkins: `if number==10**(len(digits)-1): return number` но лучше конечно найти где баг.

Comment: @jfc спасибо, пытаюсь найти.

Answer (score 2):

Строго говоря, ЛЮБОЕ ЧИСЛО ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ЧАСТЬЮ БЕСКОНЕЧНОЙ ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТИ натуральных чисел. Просто по определению.

А вот поиск минимального такого вхождения...

Поскольку всегда можно изобразить число, первое вхождение которого соответствует самому числу (например, 1000...000), то никакой алгоритм не сможет быть лучше, чем O(количество цифр до этого числа), или, если искомое число состоит из N цифр, то что-то типа `O(N*10^N)`.

Comment: Мнимая единица—это пример числа,  которое не является частью бесконечной последовательности натуральных чисел. Цифры числа π (3 1 4 1 5...) вероятно являются частью последовательности цифр, представленной в вопросе, но это не очевидно. Если же рассматривать только натуральные числа, то вопрос был бы тривиальным без требования найти конкретное место в последовательности для заданного числа (не обязательно  "минимальный индекс", но автора интересует именно первое такое вхождение).

Comment: @jfs очевидно, что речь идет о натуральных числах, как конечных последовательностях цифр. Не менее очевидно, что всегда можно указать число, первое вхождение цифр которого будут соответствовать самому числу. Так что любой алгоритм в худшем случае будет иметь не лучше чем линейное время работы от числа цифр, где встречается это число.

Comment: очевидно, что не стоит вещи, по которым разногласия возникают, называть очевидными

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению больше вариантов нет. Один раз по всей последовательности в любом случае пройти придется!

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! У меня еще есть одна идейка)